# Liferay theme deployment

Tags: deployment, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I've developed a custom theme for Liferay 6.1.1 and it's working fine on my local installation of Liferay. When I try and deploy to my QA server, the theme shows up in the control panel and I'm able to assign the new theme under Control Panel->Site Pages->Look and Feel.

The problem is that thought the theme is assigned, the customization I've done is not reflected in the UI.

The process I'm using to deploy is:

1. Create theme-name.war file by using the Eclipse "Export" functionality.
2. Place the war file in the deploy directory.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _Create theme-name.war file by using the Eclipse "Export" functionality._ Is it not possible to build the WAR with Liferay's plugins-SDK using then Ant build tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open the XML file `build-common-theme.xml` under the `themes` folder in your SDK and remove all the `preservelastmodified="true"` (or set them to `false`).

**preservelastmodified**, when `true` will not update the files timestamp in your theme project. Therefore, your application server will not detect the changes and redeploy the theme.

Comment: preservelastmodified is set to true on my local machine but any new themes that I deploy are detected. Why does the same thing not happen on the QA server? By the way, I'm using the bundled Tomcat 7 server for local development and a JBoss server on the QA. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes but I think it is more due to different operating systems.  https://www.themeray.com

Comment: I forgot also to mention that you are maybe using your liferay locally on dev mode

Comment: I just checked and I'm not using dev mode locally.

Comment: Check this out [link](http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29690) http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-29690

Comment: Even though it's rather late, THANK YOU FOR THIS. I've been trying to troubleshoot my problem for a day and a half to no avail. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should clear the browser cache and then check again.It happened to one of my theme as well.